# Install Ubuntu12.04.3 LTS with EXT4FS

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

I have a problem to install **Ubuntu12.04.3 LTS** in my computer.

My Computer is DELL(CPU: P4, 3GHz RAM: 1GB HDD: 20GB).

I downloaded **Ubuntu12.04.3 LTS** and installed this by using **wubi**.

Then it was installed on **rootfs.img** file in **FAT32** file system.

But I want to install Ubuntu on **EXT4** file system.

Comment: You need to install from the full image, either as a secondary OS or as a replacement for your existing Windows install. The `wubi` install is to install inside the Windows system.

Comment: Just take the giant leap of faith, over-write anything remotely resembling a Windows partition and commit to Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry, I am pretty ubuntu developer, I love ubuntu. but I could't  install ubuntu. please answer me, where is the full image? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wubi is used to install Ubuntu inside windows so that ubuntu will look like as any application inside windows and for that wui will install ubuntu using a filesystem that windows could understand and sure that windows will not recognize EXT2/3/4.

For that you can't install ubuntu usign wubi with ext4 filesystem.

You have to install Ubuntu standalone or if you want to keep windows you can just install it alongside windows.

For more information and learn how to install Ubuntu you have to read [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)